# vagrant and my virtual machine - vagrant reload - default: VM not created. Moving on

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, localhost, virtual-machine, vagrant-provision

I went to load up my dev/localhost environment today and when i opened terminal and `cd ..` to my destination localhost folder. I do what i do everyday and i `vagrant reload`. Generally my localhost is up in about 30 seconds after entering my password.

Today when i tried to `vagrant reload` i got the message "**default: VM not created. Moving on...**"

I then tried to `vagrant up` to see if it was maybe down for some reason and i got the error message

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/me/Documents/Development/website/www/base
```

On the browser side of things the page just looks like this:

```
Index of /

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.webite.com Port 80
```

How do i get my localhost running again? It's like my machine was deleted or disappeared.

My vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "magento"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8085

  # config.vm.network :public_network
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.19.88"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    #vb.gui = true
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
    vb.cpus = 4

  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that vagrant created another VM in virtual box while the correct instance existed.

To be able to operate the correct virtual box VM from vagrant, follow the steps:

1. run `VBoxManage list runningvms` and note the ID of the VM that you want to operate
2. edit the file `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` and set the ID found in step above
3. run vagrant command (halt/up) will operate the expected VM

**OLD ANSWER**
If you use a custom `base` box its probably better to:

1. add the box to vagrant

   ```
   vagrant box add <name of your box : base> <path to the box file>
   ```
2. init and up vagrant with this box

   ```
   vagrant box init <name of your box : base>
   vagrant up
   ```

If you want to reference a `config.vm.box_url` to be a local file you must specify as the path to the box file (not a directory - vagrant will uncompress for you)

```
config.vm.box_url = "file://<path to a box file>"
```

Comment: I tried that and this was my error message: The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

Comment: where did you get your box ? do you know how it was packaged

Comment: I think i accidentally over wrote my local.xml file and my original Vagrant file in my www folder when i did a git rebase upstream/develop yesterday. They were missing after that and my dev environment was broken as it still is....  i don't know the answer to your questions.

Comment: do you know which box you want to use ?

Comment: I know which box i want to use, yes.

Comment: ok is it the correct one mentioned from your Vagrantfile ? can you redownload the box and add again to vagrant if needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113062/discussion-between-thismethod-and-frederic-henri).